# How can I set a *.png image in drawable folder to a bitmap variable and get the color?

Tags: android

I've tried the following code but it returns a null exception.

```
try {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sampleimage);
    Toast.makeText(NamanMap.this, image.getPixel(10, 10), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(NamanMap.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and the exception is due to the `image.getPixel` function.

The problem caused by size of my image. Its resolution is: 25000 * 17000.

Comment: Does your Bitmap image contain a valid object or is it also null?

Comment: it works fine for me... check whether you have the proper image.. even if i set the pixel larger than image the exception will rise and else block invoked correctly..

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner with java/android development but try using the following code:

```
 String.valueOf(image.getPixel(10,10))
```

Comment: image.getPixel() return the int value and it the primitive type so there is no such method to convert the int to string using ToString() instead you can use String.valueOf(image.getPixel(10,10))

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but it's not related to string or int. I can't work with image.

Comment: The problem caused by size of my image. Its resolution is: 25000 * 17000.

Thanks every one.

Comment: A tenth of that resolution won't even fit my desktop monitor. Why the heck do you want to use a 25k*17k image in a cellphone?